# Error loading Gradle in IntelliJ: 'main:could not resolve com.example.newproject:essm-session-facade:1.1.31' - how to fix?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am getting this error while loading gradle in intellij
my-project: main:could not resolve com.example.newproject:essm-session-facade:1.1.31
Required by:
Project:
Possible solution:
-Declare repository providing the artifact

I tried to invalidate caches and refreshed gradle